# Current charset of the windows script host

Tags: shell, vbscript, jscript, wsh

I write script (js or vbs, not significant) with Windows Script Host that creating .bat file.

I want to convert ANSI string to OEM with ADODB.Stream

I may get current OEM code page with `Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c chcp").StdOut.ReadAll, ":")(1)` and then convent it to charset with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

How I may get the current ANSI(script) charset?

Comment: Why do you need that? Where does the "ANSI" string come from?

Comment: This is scenario for automatic deployment. For example in Russian environment Windows would have OEM charset "CP866" and ANSI charset "windows-1251". windows-1251 is charset of script itself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page Also part of code is auto-generated with UTF8 strings. I need explicit information about charsets.

Comment: You can check the code set via [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but again: why? What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: Simplest scenario: store data with customer strings and field with charset value. This will allow serialize/deserialize data and generate new data for different endpoints with different charsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows codepage can be determined via WMI, by reading the `CodeSet` property of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

There are several ways for reading properties of that class. In batch scripts you'd use the commandline executable `wmic`:

```
wmic os get codeset
```

In VBScript you could shell out and use the same command, but then you'd have to parse text output to get the actual value. It's better to do it this way:

```vb
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

For Each os In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
  cs = os.CodeSet
Next

WScript.Echo cs
```